# Generate all strings under length N in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I tried coding this myself and horribly failed. This is basically what I want:

```
a
b
...
z
aa
ba
...
za
ab
bb
...
zz
aaa
baa
...
zzz
```

In the end it should have generated every string that is shorter then N characters with charset a-z. So I'm not looking for **permutations** (of which 1001 implementations can be found on the internet), but for **combinations with replacement** (at least that's how it's called in Python). **Order is not important**, speed is.

Comment: You haven't been specific enough. Just as you've generated "baa", would you also generate "aba", "abb", and "aab"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you want it in C, here is a way to do it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int inc(char *c){
    if(c[0]==0) return 0;
    if(c[0]=='z'){
        c[0]='a';
        return inc(c+sizeof(char));
    }   
    c[0]++;
    return 1;
}

int main(void){
    int n = 3;
    int i,j;
    char *c = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<i;j++) c[j]='a';
        c[i]=0;
        do {
            printf("%s\n",c);
        } while(inc(c));
    }
    free(c);
}
```

Comment: That's nearly perfect, it just skips the first iteration (a, aa, aaa). Changing `while(inc(c))` to a `do ... while ();` loop fixed that. There is also no reason to use `malloc` here, since I won't be reserving megabytes (let alone we shouldn't cast `malloc` in C). Other then those minor details enjoy your accepted answer and +1 :)

Comment: Good catch, I fixed the do-while thing. As for casting the malloc, that's probably because I learned C with some old style compiler that was complaining when I didn't...

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition. This means `inc(c + sizeof(char))` works correctly, but looks wrong since pointer arithmetic is already done in units of the corresponding type.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
void CompWithRep(string line,int N) {
  char c;
  if (N==0) return;
  for (c = 'a' ; c <= 'z' ; c++ )
  {
    printf(line + c);
    CompWithRep(line + c,N-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing variables c, i and a.

Comment: @Yochai, please study this line `for (c = 'a' ; c < 26 ; c++ )` and study the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: loop through the letters. concat the new letter to the line you already have, send recursively to the depth of N. Don't remember exact C syntax with strings and such.

Comment: @Yochai: I think that @nightcracker is saying that you should have `for(c='a'; c < 26+'a'; c++)`

Comment: Yea, fixed that to <= 'z' , just gave a general solution in a sort of pseudocode, didn't expect everyone fixing every line. I'm sure you can't concat strings like that in C as well, if anyone want to mention it...

Comment: This algorithm works, yes, but is nowhere near as fast as some counting in base26 system as suggested by Apalala.

Comment: Depends on implementation. The exact same number of iterations occur obviously, here there's a single call to a function, in Apalala's idea you need to parse the number back to letters which is another O(N) operations on each iteration.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer: Not in C, `strcat()` is  nowhere as efficient as building the number using a base26 counter.