# Android - All possible character permutation to match string? [Restatement]

Tags: java, android, algorithm, permutation

Last time I asked this question but it was removed and I was asked to state it more precisely. (Plz note this algorithm has a very important task in my encryption app but to make it simpler, I have used program password example).

Consider password of a program to be abc123. It is locked and we have to unlock it. Consider we don't know it. Now I have to write a program that will go through all possible character permutations until I get the password and the program unlocks.

For eg it must first go through a-z then 0-9 then it will start all possible 2 character permutation - aa, ab, ac then a1, a2, a3 then ba, bb, bc etc. It will go on till z9. Then it will go through all three character possible permutation. This will continue until the program reaches abc123.

Even creating lot of loops didn't work as we don't actually know how long it the password.

Comment: you are unnecessarily creating a needle in the haystack situation. If it is you who is encrypting the password then why do you need to use bruteforce tactic to decrypt the password?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: I'm not using it as a bruteforce tactic to decrypt it. It's just a new idea by me to "encrypt" the text.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about encryption and decryption and more suitable for http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: if u just don't know the answer then plz don't put a negative vote. Plz explain me the reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate all strings under length N in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764608/generate-all-strings-under-length-n-in-c)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't check C. I just searched for it in Java and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of recursive method calls. For a 3-letter String, you'd want to iterate all possible chars on the last index. Then you'd want to iterate all possible chars over the second last **and** the last index, et cetera. Keep that in mind

```
private static List<Character> all = new ArrayList<Character>(); //your own collection chars
private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 10; //max password length
static {
    // add '0' to '9' and 'A' to 'Z' here in the same manner. 
    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) 
        all.add((char)i);
}

public void go() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_LENGTH; i++)
        inputWordsWithLength(i);
}

// entrypoint for a word with a certain length
private void inputWordsWithLength(int wordlength) {
    char[] word = new char[wordlength];
    start(word);
    doForRange(word, 0, wordlength - 1);
}

// this method is responsible for character mutation on only one index,
// and recursively calls itself
private void doForRange(char[] word, int index, int lastindex) {
    for (char c : all) {
        word[index] = c;
        for (int i = index + 1; i <= lastindex; i++) {
            doForRange(word, i, lastindex);
        }
        inputWordIntoGUI(word);
    }
}

// inject the word into your GUI
private void inputWordIntoGUI(char[] word) {
    //implement this yourself.
}

// set the value on 'aaa', for example. Not necessary, but failsafe.
private void start(char[] word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        word[i] = all[0];
}
```

This is all merely a possibility though, there are other ways, and you'll have to understand what you actually want to do before asking a question, because the/a solution is fairly simple to find.