Variable number of nested array iterations in C
First, sorry if the title is not clear, but I don't know how to ask this properly.
Imagine I have an array of N elements, in this case 4:
#define ELEMENT_COUNT 4
int arr[ELEMENT_COUNT] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };

If I wanted to get all the possible pairs formed with those elements (it doesn't matter if elements repeat), I would do something like this:
for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENT_COUNT; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < ELEMENT_COUNT; j++)
        printf("%c %c\n", arr[i], arr[j]);

I would get the following output:
a a
a b
a c
a d
b a
b b
b c
b d
c a
c b
c c
c d
d a
d b
d c
d d

What if, instead of pairs, I wanted to print all the possible groups of 3? Of course, I could keep adding nested loops, but what if the number of elements in these "groups" is not known until runtime?
The desired output would be something like this:
// For groups of 3 (64 lines)
a a a
a a b
a a c
...

// For groups of 4 (256 lines)
a a a a
a a a b
a a a c
...


does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764983/4272651

What EP called a duplicate is for a different language.

Does this answer your question? How to design a variable number of nested for-loops?

@anatolyg I don't think so, because I can't access the indexes of "parent loops" from there, right? In my opinion, his answer is not really clear, because if he just needed to iterate N elements J times, he could have used a single for that iterated N^J times.

2 approaches off the top of my head. First is recursion. Second is a single loop with a variable that indexes into an array of N indexes to advance through all the possibilities. The array starts with contents of 0, ), ... and the current index variable at the last element (N-1). You then advance forward, backtracking with the current index variable when needed and end the loop when the current index variable attempts to backtrack past the first element of the index array. I'd prefer the second, but it is a lot more mental overhead to figure out and understand.

@AviBerger Your second approach is basically what I had in mind, but I was not sure if it would work/if it was the best way. About your first approach, how would you keep track of the indexes of each "for" loop using recursion?

I'm not sure if this is what has been suggested above, but the approach I generally recommend is to emulate an N-digit odometer in base ELEMENT_COUNT. Each digit corresponds to the array index for each element of the result.

@Barmar: You mean like this?

In the recursion you could pass a string and number of additional levels needed, at each level copy the sting and in a loop extend by 1 make recursive call. Or you could use a similar index array scheme as in other approach passing the index array, current level and max levels down the recursive chain. I have used a modified version of the second one in a situation where various criteria needed to be met as well.

@Barmar, Yes, you're just more concise and maybe clearer.

There are mutliple ways of doing so. Some using recursion, other managing the loop indexes through some additional structures.
Here is the example of how I did it without recursion :
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    n += 1;
    char arr[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        arr[i] = 'a' + i;
    }

    int count[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    while( count[0] == 0 ){
        
        for(int i=1; i<n; ++i){
            printf("%c ", arr[count[i]]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        for(int i=n-1; i>=0; --i){
            if(count[i] == n-2){
                count[i] = 0;
            } else {
                count[i] += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

The code could easily be improved I guess, but it is functional at least.
The idea is to iterate over all possible permutations, by saving the current element index for each 'rank' in another structure.
I add an additional rank at the beginning to detect the overflow when all permutations have been processed.

Your arr variable is set but never used, but I get the idea.

@trxgnyp1 yeah, the code was a version I did test against, here is an update

You can do this by constructing some data to act as an iterator and treating it as a single thing that is iterated.  That data will contain a separate counter for each dimension you wish to iterate, and it will be initialized, tested, and incremented by functions that themselves iterate over each dimension.  Here is an example using a simple array for the counters.
#include <string.h>


//  Initialize counters to zero.
static void InitializeCounters(long N, long *Counters)
{
    memset(Counters, 0, N * sizeof *Counters);
}


//  Return true if there are more values to iterate, false otherwise.
static _Bool MoreToIterate(long N, long *Counters, const long End)
{
    return Counters[0] < End;
}


//  Increment the counters, lexicographic (dictionary/odometer) style.
static void IncrementCounters(long N, long *Counters, const long End)
{
    /*  Increment each dimension (except the first will be special).  If it
        rolls over its end, reset it to zero and go on the next dimension.
        If it does not roll over, stop there.
    */
    for (long i = N-1; 0 < i; --i)
        if (++Counters[i] < End)
            return;
        else
            Counters[i] = 0;

    /*  For dimension zero, do not reset it, so MoreToIterate can see it
        finished.
    */
    ++Counters[0];
}


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static void _Noreturn Usage(char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <number of elements per group>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


//  Define the set of items to draw from.
char Population[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
#define ElementCount    (sizeof Population / sizeof *Population)


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //  Parse argument.

    if (argc != 2)
        Usage(argv);

    char *end;
    long ElementsPerGroup = strtol(argv[1], &end, 0);
    if (*end != '\0')
        Usage(argv);

    if (ElementsPerGroup < 0)
        Usage(argv);

    //  Allocate one counter for each element in a group.
    long *Counters = malloc(ElementsPerGroup * sizeof *Counters);
    if (!Counters)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*  Use a traditional for loop to initialize the counters, test whether
        we are done, and increment the counters.
    */
    for (   InitializeCounters(ElementsPerGroup, Counters);
            MoreToIterate(ElementsPerGroup, Counters, ElementCount);
            IncrementCounters(ElementsPerGroup, Counters, ElementCount))
    {
        //  Print the elements in the curerent group.
        for (long i = 0; i < ElementsPerGroup; ++i)
            printf("%c ", Population[Counters[i]]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(Counters);
}


I did it with recursion :-)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
#define SYMBOLS "hu4-"
 
void recurse(char *x, int currlevel, int maxlevel) {
    if (currlevel == maxlevel) {
        // last level
        printf("%s\n", x);
    } else {
        // add one level
        for (int k = 0; k < strlen(SYMBOLS); k++) {
            x[currlevel] = SYMBOLS[k];
            recurse(x, currlevel + 1, maxlevel);
        }
    }
}
 
int main(void) {
    int loops = 5;
    char *x = calloc(loops + 1, 1); // assume OK
    recurse(x, 0, loops);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}

See https://ideone.com/38ThQ5


What if, instead of pairs, I wanted to print all the possible groups of 3? Of course, I could keep adding nested loops, but what if the number of elements in these "groups" is not known until runtime?

C++ has std::next_permutation in the header algorithm, that does something similar. But it uses the notion of a permutation with no repetitions. And uses iterators, a C++ thing.
I will show a way to implement this in C as
    int   so_next_permutation(Perm*, const char* msg);

The idea is the same of the C++ next_permutation: the function returns 0 when there are no more permutations, or returns 1 after printing the next permutation on stdout. Perm is a simple struct that abstracts the control of the iterations. Two helper functions are used:

Perm* so_create_perm( size_t sample, size_t size, void** source, int (*show)(void**, size_t));
Perm* so_destroy_perm(Perm*);

The arguments are self-explanatory:

sample size: total of items in each permutation

size: total of items in array

show is a function that knows how to display one item (not a permutation)
I will show two examples. Complete code is at the end.


This works maybe for any type of array or struct and for any size of the sample
Example 1
This one uses the array in the original question.
The user must supply a function show like:
    int show_one(void**, size_t);

In this case it can be as simple as
int show_one(void** source, size_t pos)
{   if (source == NULL) return -1;
    char* p = (char*)source;
    printf("%c", p[pos]);
    return 0;
}

The reason for this is to have a generic next_permutation that works for any array content. The program just calls next_permutation until it returns 0. The code here just prints the next permutation, but can be easily changed to return a string with the permutation
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t size = 1;
    if (argc > 1) size = atoi(argv[1]);
    char  my_test[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    size_t n_items   = sizeof(my_test) / sizeof(my_test[0]);
    Perm*  p         = so_create_perm(
        size, n_items, (void**)my_test, show_one);
    size_t count   = 0;
    char   msg[20] = {0};
    do {
        count += 1;
        sprintf(msg, "\t\t#%04d ", (int)count);
    } while (so_next_permutation(p, msg) != 0);
    p = so_destroy_perm(p);
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "\n\t%llu perm. (with "
        "repetition) of size %llu. Set of %llu "
        "items. \n",
        count, size, n_items);
    return 0;
};

The use is simple: if called with no arguments it will assume just one item for each permutation, just listing the items. Or the user can set the sample size as an argument.
output  1
Below we see the output for some sample sizes.

SO > v0
                #0001 [ a ]
                #0002 [ b ]
                #0003 [ c ]
                #0004 [ d ]

        4 perm. (with repetition) of size 1. Set of 4 items.

SO > v0 2
                #0001 [ a, a ]
                #0002 [ b, a ]
                #0003 [ c, a ]
                #0004 [ d, a ]
                #0005 [ a, b ]
                #0006 [ b, b ]
                #0007 [ c, b ]
                #0008 [ d, b ]
                #0009 [ a, c ]
                #0010 [ b, c ]
                #0011 [ c, c ]
                #0012 [ d, c ]
                #0013 [ a, d ]
                #0014 [ b, d ]
                #0015 [ c, d ]
                #0016 [ d, d ]

        16 perm. (with repetition) of size 2. Set of 4 items.

SO > v0 4
                #0001 [ a, a, a, a ]
                #0002 [ b, a, a, a ]
                #0003 [ c, a, a, a ]
 // truncated...
                #0255 [ c, d, d, d ]
                #0256 [ d, d, d, d ]

        256 perm. (with repetition) of size 4. Set of 4 items.

SO >

Example 2
This one uses an array of strings. The user just needs to write a new show function that does the expected.
The example uses this simple one:
int show_one(void** source, size_t pos)
{
    if (source == NULL) return -1;
    const char** array = (const char**)source;
    printf("\"%s\"", array[pos]);
    return 0;
}

Here is the code for maim (complete compilable code is at the end)
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    size_t size = 1;
    if (argc > 1) size = atoi(argv[1]);
    const char* my_test[] = {
        "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    size_t n_items = sizeof(my_test)/sizeof(my_test[0]);
    Perm*        p = so_create_perm(
        size, n_items,
        (void**)my_test, show_one);
    size_t count   = 0;
    char         msg[20] = {0};
    do {
        count += 1;
        sprintf(msg, "\t\t#%04d ", (int)count);
    } while (so_next_perm(p, msg) != 0);
    p = so_destroy_perm(p);
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "\n\t%llu perm. (with "
        "repetition) of size %llu. Set of %llu "
        "items. \n",
        count, size, n_items);
    return 0;
};

output 2

SO > v1
                #0001 [ "10" ]
                #0002 [ "Joker" ]
                #0003 [ "Queen" ]
                #0004 [ "King" ]
                #0005 [ "Ace" ]

        5 perm. (with repetition) of size 1. Set of 5 items.

SO > v1 2
                #0001 [ "10", "10" ]
                #0002 [ "Joker", "10" ]
                #0003 [ "Queen", "10" ]
                #0004 [ "King", "10" ]
                #0005 [ "Ace", "10" ]
                #0006 [ "10", "Joker" ]
                #0007 [ "Joker", "Joker" ]
                #0008 [ "Queen", "Joker" ]
                #0009 [ "King", "Joker" ]
                #0010 [ "Ace", "Joker" ]
                #0011 [ "10", "Queen" ]
                #0012 [ "Joker", "Queen" ]
                #0013 [ "Queen", "Queen" ]
                #0014 [ "King", "Queen" ]
                #0015 [ "Ace", "Queen" ]
                #0016 [ "10", "King" ]
                #0017 [ "Joker", "King" ]
                #0018 [ "Queen", "King" ]
                #0019 [ "King", "King" ]
                #0020 [ "Ace", "King" ]
                #0021 [ "10", "Ace" ]
                #0022 [ "Joker", "Ace" ]
                #0023 [ "Queen", "Ace" ]
                #0024 [ "King", "Ace" ]
                #0025 [ "Ace", "Ace" ]

        25 perm. (with repetition) of size 2. Set of 5 items.

SO > v1 4
                #0001 [ "10", "10", "10", "10" ]
                #0002 [ "Joker", "10", "10", "10" ]
                #0003 [ "Queen", "10", "10", "10" ]
                #0004 [ "King", "10", "10", "10" ]
                #0005 [ "Ace", "10", "10", "10" ]
//... truncated
                #0624 [ "King", "Ace", "Ace", "Ace" ]
                #0625 [ "Ace", "Ace", "Ace", "Ace" ]

        625 perm. (with repetition) of size 4. Set of 5 items.
        

code
header perm.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t array_size;
    size_t sample_size;

    void** source;
    int (*show_one)(void** source, size_t size);

    size_t  curr_dim;
    size_t* control;
} Perm;

Perm* so_create_perm(
    size_t sample, size_t size, void** source,
    int (*show)(void**, size_t));
Perm* so_destroy_perm(Perm*);
int   so_next_permutation(Perm*, const char* msg);

Here is the struct that abstracts the process. C has no self pointer like Python so the operations get a pointer to instance thing. source is the polymorphic component. control is an inverted array with the indexes.
a possible implementation for perm.c
#include "perm.h"
#include <stdio.h>

Perm* so_create_perm(
    size_t sample, size_t size, void** source,
    int (*show)(void**, size_t))
{
    if (sample == 0) return NULL;
    if (size == 0) return NULL;
    if (sample > size) return NULL;
    Perm * perm = malloc(sizeof(Perm));
    if (perm == NULL) return NULL;
    perm->array_size  = size;
    perm->sample_size = sample;
    perm->curr_dim    = 0;
    perm->source      = source;
    perm->show_one    = show;
    perm->control =
        malloc(perm->sample_size * sizeof(size_t));
    if (perm->control == NULL)
    {
        free(perm);
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "Error: could not allocate control array\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < perm->sample_size; i += 1)
    {
        perm->control[i] = 0;
    };
    return perm;
};

Perm* so_destroy_perm(Perm* to_go)
{
    if (to_go == NULL) return NULL;
    free(to_go->control);
    free(to_go);
    return NULL;
};

int so_next_permutation(Perm* perm, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL)
        printf("%s[ ", msg);
    else
        printf("[ ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < perm->sample_size - 1; i += 1)
    {
        perm->show_one(perm->source, perm->control[i]);
        printf(", ");
    }
    perm->show_one(
        perm->source, perm->control[perm->sample_size - 1]);
    printf(" ]\n");
    // update control indexes
    if (perm->control[0] < perm->array_size - 1)
    {
        perm->control[0] += 1;
        return 1;
    }
    // end of a dimension
    perm->control[0] = 0;
    for (size_t dim = 1; dim < perm->sample_size; dim += 1)
    {
        if (perm->control[dim] < perm->array_size - 1)
        {
            perm->control[dim] += 1;
            return 1;
        };
        perm->control[dim] = 0;
    };
    return 0;
}

example 1 in v0.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "perm.h"

int show_one(void**, size_t);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t sample_size = 1;
    if (argc > 1) sample_size = atoi(argv[1]);
    char   my_test[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    size_t n_items   = sizeof(my_test) / sizeof(my_test[0]);
    Perm*  p         = so_create_perm(
        sample_size, n_items, (void**)my_test, show_one);
    size_t count   = 0;
    char   msg[20] = {0};
    do {
        count += 1;
        sprintf(msg, "\t\t#%04d ", (int)count);
    } while (so_next_permutation(p, msg) != 0);
    p = so_destroy_perm(p);
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "\n\t%llu perm. (with "
        "repetition) of size %llu. Set of %llu "
        "items. \n",
        count, sample_size, n_items);
    return 0;
};

int show_one(void** source, size_t pos)
{   if (source == NULL) return -1;
    char* p = (char*)source;
    printf("%c", p[pos]);
    return 0;
}

example 2 in v1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "perm.h"

int show_one(void**, size_t);

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    size_t size = 1;
    if (argc > 1) size = atoi(argv[1]);
    const char* my_test[] = {
        "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    size_t n_items = sizeof(my_test)/sizeof(my_test[0]);
    Perm*        p = so_create_perm(
        size, n_items,
        (void**)my_test, show_one);
    size_t count   = 0;
    char         msg[20] = {0};
    do {
        count += 1;
        sprintf(msg, "\t\t#%04d ", (int)count);
    } while (so_next_permutation(p, msg) != 0);
    p = so_destroy_perm(p);
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "\n\t%llu perm. (with "
        "repetition) of size %llu. Set of %llu "
        "items. \n",
        count, size, n_items);
    return 0;
};

int show_one(void** source, size_t pos)
{
    if (source == NULL) return -1;
    const char** array = (const char**)source;
    printf("\"%s\"", array[pos]);
    return 0;
}

about next_permutation
Complete code is above, but this is where the permutations are calculated in next_permutation code:
    // update control indexes
    if (perm->control[0] < perm->array_size - 1)
    {
        perm->control[0] += 1;
        return 1;
    }
    // end of a dimension
    perm->control[0] = 0;
    for (size_t dim = 1; dim < perm->sample_size; dim += 1)
    {
        if (perm->control[dim] < perm->array_size - 1)
        {
            perm->control[dim] += 1;
            return 1;
        };
        perm->control[dim] = 0;
    };


This is the code I ended up using, pretty similar to @PoneyUHC's answer.
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf(), putchar() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* calloc(), free() */

#define ARR_SZ 4

int main(void) {
    int arr[ARR_SZ] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };

    /* This would be the run-time nesting level. Change it to see the
     * difference. */
    const int max_nesting = 3;
    int* indexes = calloc(max_nesting, sizeof(int));

    /* While the outer-most loop isn't done */
    while (indexes[0] < ARR_SZ) {
        /* This would be the body of the innermost loop. It can access all the
         * loop counters by traversing the `indexes' array. */
        for (int i = 0; i < max_nesting; i++)
            printf("%c ", arr[indexes[i]]);
        putchar('\n');

        /* Increase necessary counters from the inner-most to the outer-most */
        for (int cur_idx = max_nesting - 1; cur_idx >= 0; cur_idx--) {
            if (cur_idx == 0 || indexes[cur_idx] + 1 < ARR_SZ) {
                indexes[cur_idx]++;
                break;
            }

            indexes[cur_idx] = 0;
        }
    }

    free(indexes);
    return 0;
}

