# How long does it take to crack a hash?

Tags: security, hash

I want to calculate the time it will take to break a SHA-256 hash. So I research and found the following calculation. If I have a password in lower letter with a length of `6 chars`, I would have `26^6`passwords right?

To calculate the time I have to divide this number by a hashrate, I guess. So if I had one RTX 3090, the hashrate would be `120 MH/s` (1.2*10^8 H/s) and than I need to calculate `26^6/(1.2*10^8)` to get the time in seconds right?

Is this idea right or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but a lowercase-latin 6 character string is also short enough that you would expect to compute this one time and put it into a database so that you could look it up in O(1). It's only a bit over 300M entries. That said, given you're 50% likely to find the answer in the first half of your search, it's so fast to crack that you might not even bother unless you were doing this often. [You don't even need a particularly fancy GPU for something on this scale.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764026/how-many-sha256-hashes-can-a-modern-computer-compute)

Note that in many cases a 6 character string can also be a 5 character string, so you need to add 26^6 + 26^5 + 26^4 + ..., but all of these together only raises this to around 320M hashes. It's a tiny space.

Adding uppercase, numbers and the easily typed symbols gets you up to 96^6 ~ 780B. On the other hand, adding just 3 more lowercase-letters (9 total) gets you to 26^9 ~ 5.4T. For brute force on random strings, longer is much more powerful than complicated.

To your specific question, note that it does matter how you implement this. You won't get these kinds of hash rates if you don't write your code in a way to maximize the GPU. For example, writing simple code that sends one value to the GPU to hash at a time, and then compares the result on the CPU could be incredibly slow (in some cases slower than just doing all the work on a CPU). Setting up your memory efficiently and maximizing things the GPU can do in parallel are very important. If you're not familiar with this kind of programming, I recommend using or studying a tool like [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/).